# naturalHeight/width on image loaded with timestamp

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an image updated by Ajax and loaded with the "timestamp trick" to force the browser to reload it with a GET request as the image is cached (see below).
But with this trick, the browser doesn't recognize the naturalHeight-Width of the image.
Any idea of getting this infos in other way?

My code:

```
$('.myDiv').after('<img src="img.jpg?timestamp=' + new Date().getTime()+'" alt="" class="myImg"/>');
var nat_height = $('.myImg')[0].naturalHeight;
var nat_width = $('.myImg')[0].naturalWidth;
```

Both are returning 0.

Comment: Have you tried adding an onload handler to the image element and checking the dimensions _after_ it loads? (The code you've shown doesn't wait for it to load...)

Comment: This is exactly what I needed! I thought of a callback without success, but never tried onLoad... Thanks!